# Navigate to destination without knowing the source

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation

I'm having a graph of navigation where if any error happened in any fragment there is one error handler for all of the fragments that will navigate the user to the error screen but to handle this navigation I need to pass the navigation action to the error handler from the source,
my question is can I navigate to a screen without action? just the destination id?

```
view?.findNavController()?.navigate(R.id.errorFragment)
```

Comment: What is the problem with this if you error fragment are on the same **NavGraph** you can navigate to it with it's id

Comment: @MohammedAlaa to be able to do that, I need to create an action for all the screens and pass it to the error handler wherever an error occurred, which I don't want to do

Comment: you can create action with the same name for every fragment as it will be the same and the passed data to this action will not be changed , then call this action

Answer (score 0):

So the answer to this if someone encountered the same situation is to create action with the same name for every fragment as it will be the same and the passed data to this action will not be changed , then call this action